# How to change this material design and pull the form to right side in css html?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/z24kaL2d/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="Bootstrap Material Design">
<meta name="keywords" content="Bootstrap Material Design, Sass">
<meta name="author" content="Federico Zivolo, Kevin Ross, and Bootstrap Material Design contributors">

<title>

  Login Form

</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">


  </head>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.margin {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.row {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-width: 300px;
}
</style>

<div id="login-page" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 z-depth-6 card-panel">
  <form class="form-signin m-x-auto">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12 center">
            <img src="../assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="responsive-img valign profile-image-login">
            <p class="center login-form-text">Login Form</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>
            <input class="validate" id="email" type="email" required="">
            <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" class="center-align">Email</label>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
            <input class="validate" id="password" type="password" required="">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">          
          <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12  login-text">
              <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" />
              <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
            <p class="margin medium-small"><a href="/register">Register Now!</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
              <p class="margin right-align medium-small"><a href="forgot-password.html">Forgot password?</a></p>
          </div>          
        </div>
  </form>

</div>

</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I am using material-design and i am not able to move the form to the right side. ho ca I able to move the form to right side as given in the image

I am not able to move the form to the right side. Please help me to have a solution in this case

This is my jsfiddle. I need to change this according to the image attached[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z24kaL2d/26/) which does what you want. The trick was to add two divs into the `card-panel`: one to hold the image and one for the form. Note the `col s6` classes on both of these divs in order to make them fit horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted your CSS to achieve the alignment and also to allow for easy insertion of an image later.

All changes are documented in the CSS. Hope this helps.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; /* Added */
}
html {
    display: table;
    /* margin: auto; Removed */
}
body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.margin {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.row {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-width: 300px;
}
#login-page { /* Added to allow for easy insert of image later */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; /* This actually moves the form to the right */
  width: 100%;
}
.row .col.s12 { /* Added to overwrite width: 100% */
  width: auto!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">




<div id="login-page" class="row">
  <div class="col s12 z-depth-6 card-panel">
    <form class="form-signin m-x-auto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 center">
          <img src="../assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="responsive-img valign profile-image-login">
          <p class="center login-form-text">Login Form</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row margin">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>
          <input class="validate" id="email" type="email" required="">
          <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" class="center-align">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row margin">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
          <input class="validate" id="password" type="password" required="">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12  login-text">
          <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" />
          <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
          <p class="margin medium-small"><a href="/register">Register Now!</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
          <p class="margin right-align medium-small"><a href="forgot-password.html">Forgot password?</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```